# Botdata.SetProperty does not save its value

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

Im using formflow, im trying to set a property to know whether or not a user has been greeted already, it sets the data without any problem **(userData.SetProperty("Greet", true);)**, 
i usually check the property after setting, but when you tried to get the value of the property already during the next run(**userData.GetProperty("Greet")**), it appears that it wasn't saved. I need this so that after the user is greeted, it will exit the form flow and try the qnadialog already.

**MessageController**

```
  public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            //ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
            //await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new QnADialog());

            #region Formflow

            // Get any saved values
            StateClient sc = activity.GetStateClient();
            BotData userData = sc.BotState.GetPrivateConversationData(
                activity.ChannelId, activity.Conversation.Id, activity.From.Id);
            var boolProfileComplete = userData.GetProperty<bool>("ProfileComplete");
            if (!boolProfileComplete)
            {
                // Call our FormFlow by calling MakeRootDialog
                await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, MakeRootDialog);
            }
            else
            {
                //Check if Personalized Greeting is done
                if (userData.GetProperty<bool>("Greet"))
                {
                    ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
                    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new QnADialog());
                }
                else
                {
                    // Get the saved profile values
                    var Name = userData.GetProperty<string>("Name");
                    userData.SetProperty<bool>("Greet", true);
                    sc.BotState.SetUserData(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id, userData);
                    ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
                    Activity replyMessage = activity.CreateReply(string.Format("Hi {0}!", Name));
                    await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(replyMessage);
                }
            }
            #endregion
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

**FormFlow**

```
 [Serializable]
public class ProfileForm
{
    // these are the fields that will hold the data
    // we will gather with the form
    [Prompt("What is your name? {||}")]
    public string Name;

    // This method 'builds' the form 
    // This method will be called by code we will place
    // in the MakeRootDialog method of the MessagesControlller.cs file
    public static IForm<ProfileForm> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<ProfileForm>()
                .Message("Welcome to the profile bot!")
                .OnCompletion(async (context, profileForm) =>
                {
                    // Set BotUserData
                    context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<bool>("ProfileComplete", true);
                    context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<string>("Name", profileForm.Name);
                    // Tell the user that the form is complete
                    await context.PostAsync("Your profile is complete.");
                })
                .Build();
    }
}
```

Comment: added setuserdata. but still error persist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you first get the private conversation datastore and then set it to the Userdata datastore. This way your changes to the private conversation store are never saved in the private conversation datastore.

Change

```
sc.BotState.SetUserData(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id, userData);
```

To

```
sc.BotState.SetPrivateConversationData(activity.ChannelId, activity.Conversation.Id, activity.From.Id, userData);
```

Comment: this works like a charm! also can you help me if this is the right way to forward the conversation to a qnadialog? it doesnt seem to work. it still shows the form dialog (is this your selection?)

 await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new QnADialog());

Comment: it doesnt seem to work. it still builds the form dialog. so it keeps on asking my name

Comment: There should only be one `Conversation.SendAsync(..)` in your controller.
The first time this method is called it creates a root dialog on the conversation stack. After that first call, the only thing it does is forwarding the Activity to the top of the conversation stack (which is still your form). To do it correctly you should start the QnADialog in the ResumeAfter method of your form call.

Comment: I decided to ask a new question since this is out of scope already. I hope you could help me there as well.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43652451/how-to-forward-conversation-from-formflow-to-qnadialog